# Java string splitting error

Tags: java, android, string, split

I need to split array of string and then save it into smaller string. Plz help me....what i am doing wrong.....

```
 for(int i=0; i<suburl.size(); i++){

       String temp = suburl.get(i);
   String[] data = temp.split(" ");

   Log.i("DATA 0", data[0]);
   Log.i("DATA 1", data[1]);
   Log.i("DATA 2", data[2]);
 }
```

here

```
 public static ArrayList<String> suburl = new ArrayList<String>();
```

where,

```
   suburl.get(0) = "alex 21 engineer"
   suburl.get(1) = "mike 22 lawyer"
   suburl.get(2) = "sunny 26 deisnger"
   suburl.get(3) = "kim 24 painter"
```

and

```
   String[] data;
```

But what i am getting error when splitting is .......

```
  01-19 20:35:09.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1672): Caused by:    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
  01-19 20:35:09.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):   at  flash.com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:119)
  01-19 20:35:09.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
  01-19 20:35:09.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

Comment: put it in a unit test and debug. No guesswork needed.

Comment: what's the line causing the "index out of bound"?

Comment: at this point,   Log.i("DATA 0", data[0]);
   Log.i("DATA 1", data[1]);

Comment: It is working fine for me. Are you sure you are getting error at String[] data?

Comment: yes...if we have this data, its causing me the error, suburl.add("alex 21 engineer"); suburl.add("xyz 21 engineer"); suburl.add("tim 21 engineer"); suburl.add("gary 21 engineer");

Comment: what i mean to say..that more than 1 value of suburl is causing...error when splitting..

Comment: are you sure your spaces are all the same character? it may be that some are thin spaces or tabs. also, post the log right before the crash.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, I am not sure what's wrong. You can cross check the input data again.

```
 List<String> suburl = new ArrayList<String>();
 suburl.add("alex 21 engineer");     
 suburl.add("xyz 21 engineer");      
 suburl.add("tim 21 engineer"); 
 suburl.add("gary 21 engineer");
 for(String temp : suburl) {
    String[] data = temp.split(" ");
    System.out.println("DATA 0 " +  data[0]);
    System.out.println("DATA 1 " + data[1]);
    System.out.println("DATA 2 " + data[2]);
}
```

Comment: single isntace woudl work fine...but multiple wont,      suburl.add("alex 21 engineer");          suburl.add("xyz 21 engineer");          suburl.add("tim 21 engineer");          suburl.add("gary 21 engineer");

Answer (score 1):

What I think is that problably, not all your strings have two spaces. Just do not do things like data[x]. Use another loop to use those strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your data in the `ArrayList` like this:

```
   suburl.get(0) = "alex 21 engineer"
   suburl.get(1) = "mike 22 lawyer"
   suburl.get(2) = "sunny 26 deisnger"
   suburl.get(3) = "kim 24 painter"
```

I think you may want to change it and do `suburl.add("alex 21 engineer");`

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me:

```
 public class TestClass {

        public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<String> suburl = new ArrayList<String>();


      suburl.add("alex 21 engineer");
   suburl.add("xyz 21 engineer"); 
   suburl.add("tim 21 engineer"); 
   suburl.add("gary 21 engineer");

       for(int i=0; i<suburl.size(); i++){

           String temp = suburl.get(i);
       String[] data = temp.split(" ");

         System.out.println(data[0]);
         System.out.println(data[1]);
         System.out.println(data[2]);
     }
```

Results:

```
   alex
21
engineer
xyz
21
engineer
tim
21
engineer
gary
21
engineer
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuo must replace `i<suburl.size();` to `i<suburl.size() - 1;`